# I am dividing by zero but no "ZeroDivisionError" is prompted

Tags: python

so I am using the quadratic equation to produce to real roots.
root1 and root2

When I divide by zero, and let `A = 0`

the two roots are `0.0`, and `-0.0`

This should've given and error: `ZeroDivisionError`

Here is my code:

```
import math
A = float( input( "\nEnter the coefficient A: " ) )

B = float( input( "\nEnter the coefficient B: " ) )

C = float( input( "\nEnter the coefficient C: " ) )

print( "\nThe coefficients of the equation:\n" )
print( "  Coefficient A = ", A )
print( "  Coefficient B = ", B )
print( "  Coefficient C = ", C )

root1 = -B + math.sqrt(B**2 - (4*A*C)) / 2*A  
root2 = -B - math.sqrt(B**2 - (4*A*C)) / 2*A


print( "\nThe roots of the equation:\n" )
print( "  Root #1 = ", round(root1,3) )  
print( "  Root #2 = ", round(root2,3) )

if A = 0 , B = 4.5, C = 8
```

output is:

```
The roots of the equation:

  Root #1 =  -4.5
  Root #2 =  -4.5
```

Comment: Hint: `/ 2 * A` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Actually, you've got the same problem on the left side of the `/` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythons is like math, orders of operations system will make it dividing by `2` than multiply with `A`, to change it, do the parenthesis like in math, also in all your operations `-B` is missing:

```
(-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)) / (2 * A)
```

Or divide twice:

```
(-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)) / 2 / A
```

Answer (score 0):

The priority of `/` and `*` is the same. So the following will multiply with `A`, not divide by it:

```
root1 = -B + math.sqrt(B**2 - (4*A*C)) / 2*A
```

Also you are only dividing the `sqrt` part, excluding the `-B`. Change it to

```
root1 = (-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)) / (2 * A)
```

or

```
root1 = (-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)) / 2 / A
```